# Android Java saving to file returning IOException

Tags: java, android, load, save

i know there's probably tons of these going around (and believe me i went through a lot when trying to get this right) but i cannot seem to get this going.
I'm trying to save a list of custom objects (cars) into a file on local storage and later on load them back by clicking a button.
I've been trying to use the FileOutputStream based on many sources i've read. of some reason this worked fine when tested using simple list of strings but when it comes to my self made objects i keep getting IO exception when trying to save. if anyone can take a look at my code and tell me what am i missing (spent over 20hr trying to sort this one myself with no luck).
P.S - saving and loading methods are being called by buttons which work fine so code was neglected.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
public static List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
String FILENAME = "carListFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonView_saveb;
    Button buttonView_loadb;

    buttonView_saveb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveb);
    buttonView_loadb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadb);

    buttonView_saveb.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView_loadb.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.saveb:
            SaveData();
            break;

            case R.id.loadb:
            LoadData();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void LoadData(){
        ArrayList<car> toReturn;
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            toReturn = (ArrayList<Car>) oi.readObject();
            oi.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load, file '"+FILENAME+"' not found");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load from file '"+FILENAME+"', Class not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to load from file '"+FILENAME+"', I/O Exception")
        }
     }

    // this method return io exception, no idea why
    public void SaveData(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream of = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            of.writeObject(diveLog);
            of.flush();
            of.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to save, file '"+FILENAME+"' not found");    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to save to file '"+FILENAME+"', I/O Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

no matter what i do this keep getting me IO exceptions.
also note that i have a button which is adding cars to the list so i wont save an empty list (although i don't see why that should matter).

Comment: you can see more details about the error using eg e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you're not calling close() on FileInputStream, neither on FileOutputStream. Are you trying to open a file which has already opened (and not closed)?

Comment: @Giovanni well im relatively new to java (to be honest been coding properly for about a week now but after reading many posts on stack overflow i've noticed that closing the object output stream will also close the file output stream, if i'm mistaken please inform me so i may resolve this

Comment: @CocoNess you're absolutely right, once i've added this line to my exception and following the error log output i've realized that my mistake was down to Car being a class object and i had to implement 'serializble' on cars class for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me.
As it seems after adding the following line:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to the exception catchers and following the logCat output i found that Car could not be serialized. A quick research revealed that, since Car object came from a class (Car.java), that class has to implement 'serializable' in order to get serialized and later on be deserialized.

so at the Car.java file :

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
```

I came across a good explanation for the whole process, perfect for someone as new to java as i am:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MisF1sxBTo